# LibreOffice 7.1.4.2 | Inserting bibliography entry into Figure caption shows `[0]` when using `Number entries` for index type

Tags: libreoffice-writer, caption, bibliography

I am writing a thesis in for which i need to have bibliography at the end.
I am using LibreOffice Writer 7.1.4.2 (OpenSUSE Leap 15.2, not sure if it's relevant)

I have added Bibliography table/index (`Insert -> Table of Contents and index -> Table of Contents, Index or Bibliography`, and for type selected `Bibliography`).

I have added my entries into the database and inserted them into the document. All works well whether I check `Number entries` for formatting or not (right-click on `Bibliography index -> Edit index -> Type -> Formatting of the Entries`), i.e all entries in text are shown either `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. or `[shortA]`, `[shortB]`, etc.

**The problem** occurs when I try to **add bibliographic entry into the caption of the figure** (to reference the article from which the image was taken), and I check `Number entries`. **Every bibliographic entry that I add into any caption is shown as** `[0]` and reference doesn't work.

In `Bibliography -> Edit Index -> Entries`, `Structure` is setup as `[shortname] Tab stop, Author, Title, url, etc.` and `Sort By` is set to `Document position`. I did it this way so when I select `Number entries` I can freely move entries anywhere and order in Bibliography table will always be correct and easy to find.

This then **appears in bibliography table as**:

```
Bibliography
[1] authorA, titleA... (added in paragraph)
[2] authorB, titleB,... (also in paragraph)
[0] authorC, titleC,... (entry added in caption of figure 1)
[3] authorD, titleD,... (in paragraph)
[0] authorE, titleE,... (entry added in caption of figure 2)
[4] authorF, titleF,... (in paragraph)
etc
```

If I don't select `Number entries`, and short name is used in the entries everything seems to be working fine, i.e. all references show short name in paragraphs and captions and in Bibliography index as well, but that doesn't suit my needs.

I've tried switching and reversing order by which I add entries (paragraph first, caption next etc), also tried updating indexes with combination of switching numbered index on/off.

I also tried removing `[short name]` from display and use Numbering in the `Paragraph -> Edit style...` settings of Bibliography but then there's a mismatch of entry value in the document and number in the Bibliography table for entries that come after entry in the caption.

Does anyone know about this problem?
Can someone help me solve it or workaround it, please?

Thanks in advance!

Nenad